# How to set custom User field using allauth save_user method from POST data

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth

So I have 2 types of users, and on one of the pages of my website I want to provide additional field `cardholder` and check if it's true during user sign-up via Google

```
class DefaultSocialAccountAdapterCustom(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        """Check if it's cardholder registration"""

        user = super().save_user(request, sociallogin, form)

        if request.data.get('cardholder', False): # <-- how to get this POST value??
            user.cardholder = True
            user.save()

        return user
```

but error I receive:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

How can I read `cardholder` value from request during user sign up via social adapter and set cardholder field of user to True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with custom serializer class of my GoogleAuthView:

```
class GoogleAuthView(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    serializer_class = CardholderSocialLoginSerializer
```

here I'm setting custom field `cardholder` by overwriting serializer's `validate()` method like this:

```
class CardholderSocialLoginSerializer(SocialLoginSerializer):
    """Adds cardholder field for Google registration"""

    cardholder = serializers.BooleanField(required=False, default=False)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        user = attrs['user']
        if attrs.get('cardholder'):
            user.cardholder = True
            user.save()
        return attrs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the POST value for cardholder, i believe you will have to implement the following code....

`if request.type == 'POST':`
`cardholder = request.POST['cardholder']`

Hopefully it helps...

Comment: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'type'
same stuff here

Comment: Im sorry its request.method

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/users/rest-auth/google/
'cardholder'
There's no such key, but I sending cardholder: true :(

Comment: Just to be clear you want to get a boolean value from a user for cardholder right ?

Comment: yes I’m sending bool and want to save bool in model